Android Intent Mistake Behaviour
I have a problem related to intent.
I write intent in splashscreen by receiving value from other application.
I have created a log for checking, whether the value has entered the correct function. and the log results show the results if there is data it will be directed to AlkitabGPT.class. and if there is no data it is directed to mainactivity.
but for behavior, when the application is still not open and receiving value from intent, the log does show data exists but is directed to mainactivity.
Is there any mistake in my code, what should I add?
private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (intent == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Intent is null, proceeding to MainActivity");
            proceedToMainActivity();
            return;
        }

        String inputPedia = intent.getStringExtra("inputPedia");
        String topic = intent.getStringExtra("topic");

        Log.d(TAG, "InputPedia: " + inputPedia);
        Log.d(TAG, "Topic: " + topic);

        if (inputPedia != null || topic != null){
            Log.d(TAG, "Data exists, proceeding to AlkitabGPT");
            proceedToAlkitabGPT(intent);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "No data, proceeding to MainActivity");
            proceedToMainActivity();
        }
    }
private void proceedToAlkitabGPT(Intent intent) {
        Intent alkitabGPTIntent = new Intent(this, AlkitabGPT.class);
        alkitabGPTIntent.putExtras(intent.getExtras());
        startActivity(alkitabGPTIntent);
        finish();
    }

    private void proceedToMainActivity() {
        new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }, 2000L);
    }

What I have done is create an if-else logic to check if one of the inputPedia or topic is in the intent then point to the AlkitabGPT.class; and if it is null then point to the mainactivity.
I also created a log to check whether each function has received the correct value.
My expectation is that when the app receives an intent when it is not yet open, it will be directed to the AlkitabGPT.class.

if (intent == null) {
Log.d(TAG, "Intent is null, proceeding to MainActivity");
proceedToMainActivity();
return;
}
what does this code mean by ?

@HanifShaikh the code mean, user will be directed to mainActivity if user has no value in intent. I have updated my question. apologize for being incomplete.

So what is the Log output you receive? it's hard to predict, there are too many things can happen here

@elpafrasdriko Since you said "the log does show data exists", may be handleIntent method is invoked 2 or more times, (e.g. invoked with null intent or null inputPedia & topic for the first time, then invoked with valid intent).
